# Improve performance of converting a large xml file (~300 MB) to relational table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, xml, xquery

So this is what I have so far:

```
--Read xml content into a XML data type variable
DECLARE @FileData XML
SELECT @FileData = CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\file_path\test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
--Read from the XML variable to create Entity-Attribute-Value table
SELECT N1.Id.value('@Id', 'varchar(50)') as Id
    , N1.Id.value('@Name', 'varchar(100)') as Name
    , N2.AttributeLongName.value('@AttributeName', 'varchar(100)') as AttributeName
    , N3.AttributeValue.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') as AttributeValue
FROM @FileData.nodes('/Data/Entities/Entity') as N1(Id) ---1st lvl Node contains the Entity
cross apply Id.nodes('Attributes/Attribute') as N2(AttributeName) --2nd lvl Node contains AttributeName
cross apply AttributeName.nodes('Values/Value') as N3(AttributeValue) --3rd lvl Node contains AttributeValue
```

This code performs decently when run against an 8 MB XML file (~15s). However, when I try to run it against a 300 MB XML file of the same structure, it takes hours.

Does this mean that the XQuery nodes() method does not scale linearly or scales worst?

Is there any other way I can improve the performance on this?

Comment: Can there really be multiple Values per Attribute? If not, can you change the structure to remove the redundant Values/Value nodes and just store the Value as the data() within the Attribute Node?

Comment: Anyway, get rid of the varchar(MAX) if you don't need it, and use text()[1] instead of "." to get the text from a node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had another look at this and can reproduce your issue.  Try adding `OPTION ( MAXDOP 1 )` to your query.  In my test rig with a 300MB file this ran in 1 min 42 seconds.  The unhinted version ran for 30 minutes at 100% CPU before I killed it.

You could also have a look at [OPENXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx).  People often say it's faster with large XML files and it appears to be in this case.  However you should be aware of the known issues with `OPENXML` ( eg can take 1/8th of buffer pool, is an old-fashioned COM .dll, you *must* call `sp_xml_removedocument` etc ).  Once you've researched the pros and cons of `OPENXML`, you could try something like this:

```
DECLARE @FileData XML

SELECT @FileData = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'd:\temp\temp.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x

DECLARE @hDoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @FileData 

SELECT *
INTO #tmp
FROM OPENXML( @hDoc, '/Data/Entities/Entity/Attributes/Attribute/Values/Value', 1 ) 
WITH
    (
    Id VARCHAR(50) '../../../../@Id',
    Name VARCHAR(100) '../../../../@Name',
    AttributeName VARCHAR(100)  '../../@AttributeName',
    AttributeValue VARCHAR(MAX) '.'
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Honestly I try and avoid it these days due to those issues; what's the point of one query going faster when you've just lopped 1/8th of your buffer pool?

Finally, the quickest and most scalable method (IMHO) is SSIS.  This version ran in about 10 seconds for the same file as the above methods in my rig.

## SSIS XML Import Method

Create a package, add a Data Flow task, add an XML Source and then each table. I created a 300MB file with the same structure as yours and it loaded in about 10 seconds, eg

[image]

Obviously you'll need extra time to query the tables you have imported but I think this is a safer method.  You could even scale it out with multiple packages.  Post back if you need more help with the package.

Comment: sorry took this long to mark this as an answer. yes, SSIS packages can be very fast while reading large xml. However, the solution i ended up with was creating a CLR function that parses the file as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a lot of work with BLObs, typically ~2MB each. If I do an SQL query and limit the number of rows returned by a simple 'WHERE ID > x AND ID < y' the time of the query is not linearly related to the number of rows returned. What I found looking at the System Monitor was that the memory used increased as time passed thus I surmise increasing the time for each row returned. Experimenting with larger BLObs I have run out of memory causing the query to abort.